# sending post request to mailchimp 2.0 from grails

Tags: grails, mailchimp, http-status-code-302, httpbuilder

currently, I am integrating my grails project with mailchimp 2.0 API (we are currently use version 1.2 from grails-mailchimp plugin)
When I send a post request with json data to mailchimp end point, I always receive this error "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily". How can I fix it ?

Here is my code using HTTPBuilder

```
def twitter = new RESTClient( "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/member-info.json")
def resp = twitter.post(
        path : '/',
        body : body1,
        requestContentType : ContentType.JSON )

assert resp.status == 200
```

my logging:

```
http.RESTClient POST https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/
conn.BasicClientConnectionManager Get connection for route {s}->https://us4.api.mailchimp.com
conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator Connecting to us4.api.mailchimp.com:443
protocol.RequestAddCookies CookieSpec selected: best-match
protocol.RequestAuthCache Auth cache not set in the context
protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
client.DefaultHttpClient Attempt 1 to execute request
conn.DefaultClientConnection Sending request: POST / HTTP/1.1
http.wire >> "POST / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "Content-Length: 106[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "Host: us4.api.mailchimp.com[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
http.wire >> "[\r][\n]"
http.headers >> POST / HTTP/1.1
http.headers >> Accept: */*
http.headers >> Content-Length: 106
http.headers >> Content-Type: application/json
http.headers >> Host: us4.api.mailchimp.com
http.headers >> Connection: Keep-Alive
http.wire >> "{"id":"xxx","emails":[{"email":"xxx"}],"apikey":"xxx-us4"}"
http.wire << "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Server: nginx[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Content-Length: 1[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Location: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Date: Sun, 10 Aug 2014 09:22:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
http.wire << "[\r][\n]"
conn.DefaultClientConnection Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
http.headers << HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
http.headers << Server: nginx
http.headers << Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
http.headers << Content-Length: 1
http.headers << Location: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/
http.headers << Date: Sun, 10 Aug 2014 09:22:24 GMT
http.headers << Connection: keep-alive
client.DefaultHttpClient Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
http.RESTClient Response code: 302; found handler: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@30198ecc
http.RESTClient Parsing response as: text/html
http.wire << "[\n]"
conn.BasicClientConnectionManager Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@5dee0bbf
conn.BasicClientConnectionManager Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
http.RESTClient Parsed data to instance of: class groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
```

It seems like I am sending http, not https (because the code 302 Moved Temporarily only for HTTP protocol), isn't it ? And if yes, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can find a way to send to mailchimp, it's simply following [httpbuilder tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/json.html)

```
    def emails = []
    emails.add(['email': email_address])
    def body1 = ['id' : id, 'emails' : emails, 'apikey': apiKey]
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/member-info.json")
    http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON ) { req ->
        body = body1
        response.success = { resp, json ->
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
            println json
        }
    }
```